# NSIS Invalid Command userInfo::GetAccountType

Tags: nsis

Total NSIS nube here. I had a script that was working, and now it isn't. It's based on an example provided on the nsis site:

```
    # This installs two files, app.exe and logo.ico, creates a start menu shortcut, builds an uninstaller, and
# adds uninstall information to the registry for Add/Remove Programs

# To get started, put this script into a folder with the two files (app.exe, logo.ico, and license.rtf -
# You'll have to create these yourself) and run makensis on it

# If you change the names "app.exe", "logo.ico", or "license.rtf" you should do a search and replace - they
# show up in a few places.
# All the other settings can be tweaked by editing the !defines at the top of this script
!define COMPANYNAME "F_YEAH"
!define DESCRIPTION "I'm stoked!"
# These three must be integers
!define VERSIONMAJOR 1
!define VERSIONMINOR 1
!define VERSIONBUILD 1
# These will be displayed by the "Click here for support information" link in "Add/Remove Programs"
# It is possible to use "mailto:" links in here to open the email client
!define HELPURL "http://..." # "Support Information" link
!define UPDATEURL "http://..." # "Product Updates" link
!define ABOUTURL "http://..." # "Publisher" link
# This is the size (in kB) of all the files copied into "Program Files"
!define INSTALLSIZE 7233

RequestExecutionLevel admin ;Require admin rights on NT6+ (When UAC is turned on)

InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\${COMPANYNAME}\${APPNAME}"

# rtf or txt file - remember if it is txt, it must be in the DOS text format (\r\n)

# This will be in the installer/uninstaller's title bar
Name "${COMPANYNAME} - ${APPNAME}"
Icon "C:\Users\dkim\Documents\dog.ico"
outFile "GetSomeGA.exe"

!include LogicLib.nsh

# Just three pages - license agreement, install location, and installation
page license
page directory
Page instfiles

!macro VerifyUserIsAdmin
UserInfo::GetName
pop $0
${If} $0 != "admin" ;Require admin rights on NT4+
        messageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"
        setErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
        quit
${EndIf}
!macroend

function .onInit
    setShellVarContext all
    !insertmacro VerifyUserIsAdmin
functionEnd

section "install"
    # Files for the install directory - to build the installer, these should be in the same directory as the install script (this file)
    setOutPath $INSTDIR
    # Files added here should be removed by the uninstaller (see section "uninstall")
    File /r "C:\Users\dkim\Documents\Projects\MOR\Projects\GAintegration\GA_ConversionOnDemand_0.1"
    File "C:\Users\dkim\Documents\dog.ico"
    # Add any other files for the install directory (license files, app data, etc) here



    # Uninstaller - See function un.onInit and section "uninstall" for configuration
    writeUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"

    # Start Menu
    createDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}"
    createShortCut "$DESKTOP\pleaseClickMe.lnk" "$INSTDIR\GA_ConversionOnDemand\GA_ConversionOnDemand_run.bat" "" "$INSTDIR\dog.ico" 0

    # Registry information for add/remove programs
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "DisplayName" "${COMPANYNAME} - 

${APPNAME} - ${DESCRIPTION}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR

\uninstall.exe$\""
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "QuietUninstallString" "$

\"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe$\" /S"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "InstallLocation" "$\"$INSTDIR$\""
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "DisplayIcon" "$\"$INSTDIR

\logo.ico$\""
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "Publisher" "$\"${COMPANYNAME}$\""
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "HelpLink" "$\"${HELPURL}$\""
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "URLUpdateInfo" "$\"${UPDATEURL}$

\""
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "URLInfoAbout" "$\"${ABOUTURL}$\""
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "DisplayVersion" "$

\"${VERSIONMAJOR}.${VERSIONMINOR}.${VERSIONBUILD}$\""
    WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "VersionMajor" ${VERSIONMAJOR}
    WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "VersionMinor" ${VERSIONMINOR}
    # There is no option for modifying or repairing the install
    WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "NoModify" 1
    WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "NoRepair" 1
    # Set the INSTALLSIZE constant (!defined at the top of this script) so Add/Remove Programs can accurately report the size
    WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}" "EstimatedSize" ${INSTALLSIZE}
sectionEnd

# Uninstaller

function un.onInit
    SetShellVarContext all

    #Verify the uninstaller - last chance to back out
    MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "Permanantly remove ${APPNAME}?" IDOK next
        Abort
    next:
#   !insertmacro VerifyUserIsAdmin
functionEnd

section "uninstall"

    # Remove Start Menu launcher

    RMDir /r "$PROGRAMFILES\${COMPANYNAME}"
    delete "$DESKTOP\click_or_die.lnk"

    # Always delete uninstaller as the last action
    delete $INSTDIR\uninstall.exe


    # Remove uninstaller information from the registry
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME} ${APPNAME}"
sectionEnd
```

The error message I get is:

```
!insertmacro: VerifyUserIsAdmin
Invalid command: UserInfo::GetName
Error in macro VerifyUserIsAdmin on macroline 1
Error in script "C:\Users\dkim\Documents\test3.nsi" on line 55 -- aborting creation process
```

It won't let me use any command involving UserInfo. Any ideas on what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler cannot find the UserInfo plugin or the plugin is corrupted.

The file should be in `%ProgramFiles%\NSIS\Plugins` in NSIS v2 and in `%ProgramFiles%\NSIS\Plugins\x86-ansi` or `%ProgramFiles%\NSIS\Plugins\x86-unicode` in NSIS v3 (depending on your target type).

This plugin is part of the default NSIS install so I would recommend that you just reinstall NSIS on top of your existing install...

Comment: Yep - thanks! it seems I did a minimal install with no plugins. All is well, now.